# Grease Pencil and also curves don't appear

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, blend-files, grease-pencil

whenever i try to draw with the grease pencil or use a curve it doesn't show up in the view port, it dose shows up in the library. 
I have tried restarting and still nothing works. I would love any help.
Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

One reason for missing annotations can be the fact that they are disabled in viewport;

1. Check your 3D viewport upper right corner menu, see if annotations is checked or not.
2. Or change Active workspace tab - Layout and Modeling tab for example show annotations by default.

[image]

Comment: Annotations are turned on, Ill update with a screenshot.